# Checking if cookie exists being ignored on smart phones

Tags: php, cookies

I have a really strange problem, it may be because of my poor coding skills as I guess my way through. However it works perfectly on the computer but does something VERY strange.

So the code detects if the cookie exists (returning user) and if it doesn't exist it creates the cookie, it then goes down and checks the location of the visitor. If it matches a country I have specified it throws a modal which in turn offers them the correct countries website.

On the phone, it works once.. But only once. I can go and get another phone that I have NEVER visited on before after that and it wont show... if I rename the cookie it then shows. Its almost like the phone has server side cookie instead of client side. That's just what its like. Very very strange. Anyway my code is below. It's not beautiful but it does work.

I have also tried running echo statements to test to see where it breaks on phones. It doesn't get past the if `isset` at the beginning. But like I said, it wont get past that stage even on a phone I have never visited that website on before. If I change the name of the cookie it shows...

```
<?php

// SET COOKIE VAR NAME AND VALUE
$cookie_name = "NAMEOFCOOKIE";
$cookie_value = "Yes";

// CHECK TO SEE IF COOKIE EXISTS ALREADY, IF IT DOESN'T CONTINUE DOWN AND CREATE NEW COOKIE
if (!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {

    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

    // GRAB GEOIP CLASS, THE VISITOR IP, CHECK TO SEE LOCATION OF VISITOR
    require_once('/home/user/public_html/geoplugin.class/geoplugin.class.php');

    $geoplugin = new geoPlugin();
    $geoplugin->locate();
    $country = "{$geoplugin->countryName}";

    if ($country == "United States") {
        // IF THE VISITORS LOCATION COUNTRY IS UNITED STATES, POP THE MODAL AND OFFER THE CORRECT COUNTRY WEBSITE AND BLOCK OUT BODY FROM SCROLLING

        $link = "http://www.otherwebsite.com";
        echo "<script src='https://www.otherwebsite.com.au/main.js'></script><script>$('body').addClass('modal-open');</script>";

    } elseif ($country == "New Zealand") {
        // IF THE VISITORS LOCATION COUNTRY IS NEW ZEALAND, POP THE MODAL AND OFFER THE CORRECT COUNTRY WEBSITE AND BLOCK OUT BODY FROM SCROLLING

        $link = "http://www.otherwebsite.co.nz";
        echo "<script src='https://www.otherwebsite.com.au/main.js'></script><script>$('body').addClass('modal-open');</script>";

    }

}
```

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you please clarify.

Comment: Sounds to me like your phone devices' browsers sync with each other.